# How to strip HTML (or other) from form input that creates URL

Tags: php, forms, xss

So i have a simple form that is used to create a URL - and then carries the user to the URL upon submit action - here's the code:

```
<form method="get" class="searchform" action="/srch">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e('Search'); ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="fwp_general_search" id="s" title="Search Field" placeholder="Enter Terms Here..." />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="searchsubmit" title="Search Button" value="Search" />
</form>
```

It works great, takes the user to the URL as intended.

However, to prevent some vulnerabilities, I'd like to be able to strip out any HTML or other tags that could be inserted in to that text field. How can I strip out tags from that input?

Comment: Uh, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: A little search won't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you'll be doing with the input on the backend. If you're using it with a database you should look into prepared statements to prevent SQL injection, and if you're also displaying the input back to the user you will want to look into securing output with escaping, using  functions such as `htmlspecialchars()`, `strip_tags()` and the like.

PHP also has functions to aid in url validation, such as https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: I'd like to use a function such as strip_tags - but do I place that function around the <input> field? I'm not using it with a database - just creating a URL.

Comment: You would use it in the php file where you collect the $_POST data, this is the php file the action attribute of the form points to.

Comment: Ah - yes. Ideally, I need the text to get sanitized before it goes in to the URL that is created. This form creates a URL and sends the user to that URL when the submit button is pressed. As as example:   

https://example.com/srch/<text-entered-in-form>

Comment: Sanitize, validate in the php file, then use a PHP redirect to the requested url.